# Нужно посчитать время выполнения операций +-/* для разных типов на с++

Tags: c++

Сначала я считаю время для первого цикла и хочу отнять время второго цикла(он будет считать время только для проверки условия цикла и операции i++) Но его время всегда 0, как сделать так, что бы компилятор не пропускал его, а реально считал время?
int a=1, b=2, c=3;

```
    unsigned time1 = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        a = b + c;
        b = a + c;
        c = a + b;
        a = b + c;
        b = a + c;
        c = a + b;
        a = b + c;
        b = a + c;
        c = a + b;
        a = b + c;
        b = a + c;
        c = a + b;
        a = b + c;
        b = a + c;
        c = a + b;
    }
        unsigned time2 = clock();

        double fullTime = 1000.0*(time2 - time1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << "FULL TIME  " << setprecision(10)<<  fixed << fullTime << endl;
    unsigned time3, time4;
    time3 = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
    }
    time4 = clock();
    double emptyTime = 1000.0*(time4 - time3)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    cout << "EMPTY TIME " << emptyTime << endl;
    cout << "Average time for operation" << endl;
    cout << (fullTime - emptyTime)/150000000.0 << endl;
```

Comment: Ну отключите оптимизацию, если это учебное задание, и вам нужно именно сравнение для разных типов. И еще - `clock()` - это так, плюс-минус два крокодила... Воспользуйтесь [`high_resolution_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock), это несколько поточнее... Потому что и в первом цикле приличный оптимизатор у вас может не захотеть выполнять все сложения. Или (реально в VC++2017) с оптимизацией использовать `lea`, без - `add` и `mov`...

Comment: Спасибо, а почему компилятор может "игнорить" первый цикл?

Comment: Не игнорить, а преобразовывать в нечто другое.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно объявить переменные `volatile`. Это запретит оптимизацию, и обяжет чтобы компилятор обязательно считывал значения переменных из памяти, а не выдумывал бы всякие оптимизации.

```
volatile int a = 1 ;
volatile int b = 2 ;
volatile int c = 3 ;
```

Comment: можете обьяснить в чем суть? проверил с ними и без них - ничего не поменялось

Comment: У вас два разных цикла, один на 10 миллионов, второй на тысячу. Вы отнимаете два разных числа, зачем? Если вы хотите правильно отнять, то второй цикл должен быть такого-же размера (10млн). И переменная `int i` - везде обязательно `volatile int i` должна быть.

Comment: `volatile` заставит компилятор генерировать команды обращения к памяти при каждом доступе к переменной (чтение ее значения и запись нового). Такой код может оказаться существенно медленнее обычного оптимизированного кода, когда все промежуточные действия на самом деле производятся с регистрами CPU

Comment: @avp `volatile` я предложил, чтобы компилятор **не** выполнял арифметические действия на уровне компиляции, чтобы проверка скорости работы была-бы близка к реальности.